# Continuity of $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R_l}$

Tags: general-topology

It seems to me that...

A mapping $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R_l}$ is continuous iff it is a constant map.

I've outlined a proof below:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R_l}$ be continuous then $f(\mathbb{R})=$ continuous image of connected set $=$ connected set $=$ single point set in $\mathbb{R_l}$, as single point sets are only connected sets in $\mathbb{R_l}$.
Conversely, if  $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R_l}$  is constant map then it is continuous because inverse of any set under f is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\phi$. Both are open in $\mathbb{R}$ . 
Am I wrong??

Comment: What is the space $\mathbb R_{\mathrm l}$?

Comment: It is $\mathbb{R}$ with lower limit topology

Comment: Yes, it's completely disconnected, so your answer is correct.