# Continuity of $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_l$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to understand why a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_l$  ($\mathbb{R}_l$ is the reals equipped with lower limit topology) is continuous iff it is a constant map. I found this [Continuity of $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R_l}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2519338/continuity-of-f-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbr-l), but I haven't studied connectedness yet so the first direction doesn't make much sense.

In particular, I don't know why single point sets are the only connected ones in $\mathbb{R}_l$ or exactly how this fits in but I want to understand the result using only the basic notion of continuity. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the exact same proof as the one using connectedness, only without the concept of connectedness being mentioned:

Say $f(\mathbb R)$ contains two distinct points $a,b$ with $a<b.$ Then $f^{-1}((-\infty,b))$ and $f^{-1}([b,\infty))$ form a partition of $\mathbb R$ into two nonempty disjoint open sets.

But this can't happen: Let $x<y$ with $x\in U_1$ and $y\in U_2$, where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are nonempty disjoint open sets partitioning $\mathbb R.$ The set $\{z\in \mathbb R: [x,z]\subseteq U_1\}$ is bounded from above (by $y$), so has a least upper bound $z_0.$ But $z_0$ is a boundary point of $U_1$ and $U_2$, so can't be contained in either, since they're open.

---

To make the connection with connectedness, the last paragraph is a proof that $\mathbb R$ is connected. The idea in the paragraph preceding is that no set in $\mathbb R_l$ with two distinct points can be connected since $(-\infty, b)$ and $[b,\infty)$ is an open partition separating the two points. And the idea that we can convert this into a nontrivial partition of $\mathbb R$ into open sets is the same idea as in the proof that the continuous image of a connected set is connected.